# Check status after verification - Twilio Verify

Tags: twilio

I have a web app with following 3-step flow using Twilio Verify for email verification:

1. Creating verification code with Verify
2. Checking verification code with Verify
3. Create user account in my web api

After a successful **Twilio Verify** verification code check (step 2), I need to be able to do another **Twilio Verfy** call to ensure that the email was verified before a user account is actually created in my web api (step 3). But since the SID is deleted after successful email verification, I get following answer for a `GET` request to:
`https://verify.twilio.com/v2/Services/{ServiceSid}/Verifications/{Sid}`

```
{
  "code": 20404,
  "message": "The requested resource /Services/VAxxx/Verifications/VExxx was not found",
  "more_info": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20404",
  "status": 404
}
```

Now, for the Frontend, it's easy: I move to the final account creation step only if the email was verified successfully.
But, for a true stateless Backend, after accepting the Frontend request I first need to double-check with Twilio if the email was actually already verified.

True stateless in the sense that I do not want to store in a DB if an email was already verified or not. (This is already done by Twilio)

How can I do that? I didn't find the right API in the Twilio documetaion.

Comment: The verification is deleted once it is verified. I'm not sure I understand your desire for true stateless-ness. There is inherent state whether it is in the API request or if you store the verification details yourself. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Basically I would like to access programmatically to this informaiton (pending, expired, approved) visible in the service logs: https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/api/verification-check#check-a-verification

Comment: That log is not available via the API. I am trying to understand what you are trying to achieve by checking the verification twice so that I can perhaps suggest an alternative. Can you help me understand?

Comment: When the frontend verifies the email through Twilio it can decide to proceed or not to the last step where the backend is called to create a new user. But the backend has no means to check the verification as well before creating new user. Baseline: similar as done with data or user input validation, the security is needed on frontend AND on backend.

Comment: How is the front-end accessing the API?

Comment: Frontend is a React SPA, that calls my .NET/C# WebAPI. There I use the Twilio C# SDK to call the Verify API. But please remeber, I would like to avoid to store information that is already stored on Twilios side. In this case the service logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I understand that you would like to get the information that appears available in the logs, however that is not available through the API. Once a verification has succeeded (or timed out after 10 minutes, or reached the maximum number of incorrect attempts) [it is deleted](https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/api/verification-check#check-a-verification) and you can no longer access it through the API. I assume this is to prevent replay attacks, but I’m not on that team, so don’t know all the reasons behind it.

The result of this is that you cannot call on the verification check more than once from your code.

You will have to store the state within your own system because the API will not store that state for you. Much like during login with 2FA you would need to store the state that a password had been successfully entered.